# Can't load websites when bridging enp0s3 with static IP

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, network-bridge, static-ip

So I was trying to bridge the enp0s3 in a VM in ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 Bit). The VM gets its internet connection through "bridged adapter", no NAT. If I go with the DHCP configuration everything works fine. In this case my **/etc/network/interfaces** looks like this:

```
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s3 inet manual

iface br0 inet dhcp

bridge_ports enp0s3
```

The DHCP assigns 192.168.1.130 to my VM. Everything working.
But if I try to use static values for my bridge br0 instead of DHCP like this:

```
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s3 inet manual

iface br0 inet static
 address      192.168.1.130
 netmask      255.255.255.0
 network      192.168.1.0
 gateway      192.168.1.1
 broadcast    192.168.1.255

bridge_ports enp0s3
```

something with my DNS or whatever breaks. I can still ping 8.8.8.8 but I can't load any website anymore. I already checked if enp0s3 was correctly added to br0 with `brctl show` which outputs

```
bridge name    bridge id    STP enabled    interfaces
br0            8000.090Xe1  no             enp0s3
```

It seems to be some kind of weird stupid problem and is probably easy to solve. Yet I can't see why its not working properly

Comment: If you want to use static, don't you need to specify DNS in the interfaces file? For example, after your broadcast line something like `dns-nameservers 192.168.111.1`

Comment: @ Doug Smythies I tryed that but it changed nothing. I tried my router as DNS as well as google 8.8.8.8. What kinda worked was editing the /etc/resolv.conf file and add a nameserver there. But it's a really crappy way to do things since the resolv.conf file gets overwritten a lot.

Comment: What router are you using? I had Linksys and Netgear.  One of them would not allow me to assign a fixed IP inside the range it assigned IP addresses.  I had to set my fixed IP outside the range. The Netgear I use now will assign a static IP for the MAC address so I quit fixing them inside the router.  

Also, you probably already know, that if another computer comes online while yours is offline, it could assign your IP and you can't connect.

I  realize this may be 'the obvious' to you, but sometimes I find people overlook the obvious so it is always good to point it out.  Hoping to help.